# How can I run a Macro when the value in a specific cell changes?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Let me preface by saying that I am very new to VB...

I am trying to run a macro whenever the value in a certain cell changes. I've read up on how to do this, but can't seem to get it to work. I have entered the following code into the private module of the worksheet object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("$C$5")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.Run _

            "'Amex Payments_Experiment.xlsm'!SelectCells"

    End If    

End Sub
```

C5 is the cell I am trying to monitor for change.
"SelectCells" is the macro I want to run.
"Amex Payments_Experiment.xlsm" is the name of the file.

When I change the value in C5 nothing happens. Some help would be great. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Cyberkiwi - No, that is not exactly how I did it, but when I follow you're instructions I do find the code where you say it should be. To get to the private module of the worksheet object I right clicked the sheet tab at the bottom, selected "view code", then selected "worksheet" from the dropdown in the top center of the page.

User587834 - Yes. Macro's are enabled.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

if you use Excel2007 be sure that macros are enabled, by default Excel 2007 deactivate macro execution for new workbook.
for that try to execute any other macro to be sure that macros are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> I have entered the following code into the private module of the worksheet object:

How exactly have you done that?  As below?

- Alt-F11 to switch to code view
- On the left, double-click on the target sheet
- On the right, do you see the code you entered? if not, proceed to next step
- Paste the code block

Answer (score 0):

This code works Ok for me

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("$C$5")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

Maybe the problem is with your Application.Run:
- select the line containing the intersect and click F9 to switch on Debug, then try changing a cell to see if you get to the sub.
If you never reach that line then you have not got the code in the worksheet clkass module, or you have switched off events, or macros are disabled or ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Application.EnableEvents` property, and set it to `True` if required.